# Ionic Framework using JSONP and the WordPress JSON-API

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress, api, ionic-framework

I am currently playing with wpIonic (https://github.com/scottopolis/wpIonic) and the sample uses WP-JSON-API V2 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/), but I have heavly bespoked another WP API for my needs (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).

The problem I am having, the wpIonic sample uses JSONP and I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
http://preview.meeko.me/api/get_posts/?post_type=product&custom_fields=all&_jsonp=JSONP
Object {data: undefined, status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "error"}
```

The API i am currently using doesn't output JSONP but the DataLoader factory for GET requests does:

```
.factory('DataLoader', function( $http ) {

  return {
    get: function(url) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return $http.jsonp( url );
    }
  }

  })
```

This is the request to get the post data in my controller:

```
 var postsApi = $rootScope.url + '/api/get_posts/?post_type=product&custom_fields=all&' + $rootScope.callback;

 $scope.moreItems = false;

 $scope.loadPosts = function() {

   // Get all of our posts
DataLoader.get( postsApi ).then(function(response) {

  $scope.posts = response.data;

  $scope.moreItems = true;

  //$log.log(response.data);

}, function(response) {
  $log.error(response);
});

 }
```

API & Callback

```
 $rootScope.url = 'http://preview.meeko.me';

 $rootScope.callback = '_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
```

Any guidence in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Am having the same issues 
i think the problem is from json-rest-api as a lot of other people are having the same issues with the V2
    using $http.get(....).success().error();
works fine for me!